# What dependencies are needed to write rust/gstreamer plugins for gstreamer crate 0.14?

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://coaxion.net/blog/2018/01/how-to-write-gstreamer-elements-in-rust-part-1-a-video-filter-for-converting-rgb-to-grayscale/ about writing gstreamer plugins using rust.

If you follow the tutorial to the first point where I have compilable code  Cargo.toml is

```
[package]
name = "gst-plugin-tutorial"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Sebastian DrÃ¶ge <sebastian@centricular.com>"]
repository = "https://github.com/sdroege/gst-plugin-rs"
license = "MIT/Apache-2.0"

[dependencies]
glib = "0.4"
gstreamer = "0.10"
gstreamer-base = "0.10"
gstreamer-video = "0.10"
gst-plugin = "0.1"

[lib]
name = "gstrstutorial"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

and src/lib.rs is

```
extern crate glib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate gstreamer as gst;
extern crate gstreamer_base as gst_base;
extern crate gstreamer_video as gst_video;
#[macro_use]
extern crate gst_plugin;

plugin_define!(
    b"rstutorial\0",
    b"Rust Tutorial Plugin\0",
    plugin_init,
    b"1.0\0",
    b"MIT/X11\0",
    b"rstutorial\0",
    b"rstutorial\0",
    b"https://github.com/sdroege/gst-plugin-rs\0",
    b"2017-12-30\0"
);

fn plugin_init(plugin: &gst::Plugin) -> bool {
    true
}
```

This compiles, but the project for which I need to write a plugin uses gstreamer 1.16, so it needs rust crate gstreamer 0.14.

When I alter the Cargo.toml to reference recent versions of the gstreamer crate:

```
[dependencies]
#glib = "0.4"
gstreamer = "0.14"
gstreamer-base = "0.14"
gstreamer-video = "0.14"
gst-plugin = "0.3.2"
```

I get errors at build time:

```
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `glib-sys`.
    ... required by package `gstreamer-base v0.14.0`
    ... which is depended on by `gst-plugin-tutorial v0.1.0 (/home/thoth/src/rust-gst-plugin-exp/coaxion-plugin)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.9` are: 0.9.0

the package `glib-sys` links to the native library `glib`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `glib` as well:
package `glib-sys v0.7.0`
    ... which is depended on by `gst-plugin v0.3.2`
    ... which is depended on by `gst-plugin-tutorial v0.1.0 (/home/thoth/src/rust-gst-plugin-exp/coaxion-plugin)`

failed to select a version for `glib-sys` which could resolve this conflict
```

What is the proper mix of crate versions to write gstreamer plugins in rust for use with gstreamer 1.16 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find new versions of the tutorials [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/tree/master/gst-plugin-tutorial) and the latest version of the code [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/tree/master/gst-plugin-tutorial).

Your problem is that you're still using the `gst-plugin` crate, but that's obsolete nowadays and everything's part of the `glib` / `gstreamer` / `gstreamer-base` / etc crates now if you enable the `subclass` feature of them. See the links above for the details.

Depending on the old version of the `gst-plugin` crate will pull in an older version of the `glib-sys` (and others) crate, and you can't have two different versions of a `-sys` crate in the same project.

You'll have the same problem again if you uncomment the `glib` dependency. Once you update that to the `0.8` version of `glib`, that error would also go away.

Comment: When I removed the gst-plugin crate and set glib to 0.8 I was unable to find the definition of the `plugin_define!` or `gst_plugin_define!` macro.  Switching from published crates to the git repos did allow me to start compiling and developing code.  I anticipate as the plugin API stabilizes it will be possible again to create plugins that use published crates.

Comment: It's possible to use the released versions on crates.io just fine. What problem were you running into? E.g. the [0.5 branch](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/tree/0.5) of the `gst-plugins-rs` repository is using released versions of everything. Check that for the tutorials code that works with releases.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on Sebastian's answer, I experimented with a Cargo.toml that doesn't point at git and uses released crates.

```
glib = "0.8"
gstreamer = "0.14"
gstreamer-base = "0.14"
gstreamer-video = "0.14"
#gst-plugin = "0.3.2"
```

That failed to provide a definition for `gst_plugin_define!` .  It seems that is part of the subclassing feature.  Switching to the following dependencies:

```
glib = { version = "0.8", features = [ "subclassing"] }
gstreamer = { version = "0.14", features = [ "subclassing"] }
gstreamer-base = { version = "0.14", features = [ "subclassing"] }
gstreamer-video = "0.14"
```

activated the code defining the `gst_plugin_define!` macro.